# What's the easiest method to keep div scrollbar at the bottom when the content in div is updated?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The code can already scroll to the bottom after a submission, but the scroll bar does not update when there is a page update.

Here is how I want the scrollbar to behave:

1) The scroll bar starts at the bottom of the div.
2) The scroll bar scrolls to the bottom of the div only if you are at the bottom of the div before the content in the **php file** is updated.
3) The scroll bar does not scroll to the bottom of the div if you are not at the bottom of the div before an update was made to the content in the **php file**.

I searched Google and here for a method to get this to work, but what I have found does not work for me in my case.

Here's the code for the div:

```
<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; width: 70%; height: 80%; overflow-y: auto; right: 0px; top: 0px;" >
<?php include ('content.php'); ?>
</div>
```

And here's the code for the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#msg').ajaxForm({
            target: '#message',
            success: function() {
$("#msg")[0].reset();
$("#div1").animate({ scrollTop: $("#div1")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: "Scroll to the bottom when you're already at the bottom"? Not sure what you're talking about here

Comment: If you are at the bottom of the page before there is a page update, you scroll down to the new bottom if there is a page update. If you aren't on the bottom before a page update, then you do not scroll down to the latest update.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect that a div is already scrolled all the way to the bottom?

Comment: Question is far too abstract. Please make expected behavior explanation more concise. If you are in middle of page, why would it end up at bottom?

Comment: I edited the question with a more concise expected behavior explanation. I numbered the 3 things I want the scrollbar to do.

Comment: you want that if div updated then should scroll to bottom otherwise as it is?

Comment: TechnoCrat: If at the bottom, scroll down to new update. If above bottom, stay as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect that the scroll bar is at the bottom you can use the following

```
function isScrolledToBottom(el) {
    return el.scrollTop == el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight;
}
```

Here's an example where

- Div starts scrolled down
- When content is added, it checks if the div was scrolled all the way down before updating content
- If it was scrolled to the bottom, it scrolls it again after updating

```js
var div  = document.getElementById('content');
// Set it to go the bottom initially
scrollToBottom(div);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var wasAtBottom = isScrolledToBottom(div);
    var scrambledText = div.innerHTML.split('').sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - .5
    }).join('');
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scrambledText));
    if (wasAtBottom) {
        scrollToBottom(div);
    }
});

function isScrolledToBottom(el) {
    return el.scrollTop == el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight;
}

function scrollToBottom(el) {
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight;
}
```

```css
#content {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin luctus imperdiet venenatis. Etiam lorem nisi, ullamcorper nec neque non, ultrices elementum lectus. Ut dapibus venenatis quam sit amet imperdiet. Proin scelerisque, nunc vitae ultricies aliquam, diam ligula venenatis purus, id egestas elit turpis sit amet velit. Suspendisse facilisis vel arcu eget hendrerit. Donec non nunc aliquam, finibus ante vitae, venenatis dolor. Suspendisse pulvinar fermentum rhoncus. Proin pulvinar lectus et purus consectetur rutrum.  Phasellus rutrum dolor risus, non consectetur erat posuere eget. Etiam viverra congue laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet ullamcorper finibus. Nulla ac vehicula risus. Phasellus nec fermentum quam. Donec blandit ornare ipsum ut dignissim. Etiam nec velit maximus, mollis nibh id, elementum nisi. Donec arcu nisi, sollicitudin sit amet metus sed, aliquet convallis eros. Sed lacus metus, aliquet sed sodales vitae, rutrum sollicitudin dolor. Nunc dictum, mi id egestas luctus, mi erat finibus enim, a imperdiet orci est ac elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse potenti. Sed dignissim viverra finibus. Ut quis nulla a sapien bibendum sodales at ut nunc. Etiam volutpat ante varius tellus vulputate blandit. Aliquam turpis purus, efficitur vel lacus imperdiet, viverra auctor nisl. Aenean nunc est, tempus nec tincidunt in, malesuada in mauris. Nam dui risus, maximus et placerat in, elementum tristique leo. Fusce quis viverra enim. Curabitur congue fringilla accumsan. Curabitur vehicula aliquet malesuada. Aliquam pharetra ante vel nulla elementum, sit amet auctor mi porttitor. Mauris id varius leo. Vestibulum ac dolor id ligula iaculis aliquam. Donec porta euismod quam, eu sollicitudin nisi interdum egestas. Vestibulum et ligula velit. Nulla vel iaculis purus. Integer et est ut ipsum fringilla rhoncus. Aliquam auctor eu arcu rhoncus maximus. Sed vulputate, ipsum nec tempus sodales, neque leo hendrerit elit, a faucibus nisl ex nec lorem. Praesent varius dictum felis, sed sollicitudin diam tempor vitae. Mauris tempus justo non egestas mollis. Etiam congue odio eget velit vulputate, sit amet pharetra nulla faucibus. Cras a lorem sed ante imperdiet dapibus id blandit risus. Pellentesque nec tincidunt lacus.</div>

<button>Add content</button>
```

Comment: It isn't working for me. I tried looking at your snippet and it isn't working as you described.

Comment: You need to work on your descriptions, "not working" does not help me understand your problem. How is it not working? What were your steps? What did you expect, what actually happened? Browser? Did you scroll the div, then click the button? The line you were reading should still be visible, it doesn't scroll to the bottom.

Comment: If you click the button while the div is scrolled to the bottom, it will stay scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: I click on your add content button and content does not get added. I am using Firefox.

Comment: What browser? I tried it in Chrome and IE 11 and it does add content

Comment: All I can see is TypeError: div.innerText is undefined

Comment: @CodeMunching I fixed that for firefox, there's no `div.innerText` anymore, refresh your page

Comment: Your snippet works very nicely, but when I implement the code, it does start at bottom, but it isn't staying at the bottom when content is added. My content is in an include('content.php'); ....

Comment: @CodeMunching I have shown you what it takes  to do it. You should update your question to show what you have actually tried, otherwise, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Thanks, your help got me to figure it out.